# e.preventDefault() is not working

Tags: jquery

The first e.preventDefault() inside the if condition is not working. Only the second e.preventDefault() is working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I made following change to the jquery, but then the form submission does not work properly and the page stops at the blank form action page checkcoupon.php instead of further processing of form.

```
<form name='coupon_discount' id='coupon_discount' action="checkcoupon.php" method='post'>
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $_SESSION[user_id]; ?>" >
        <input value="" id="couponCode" name="couponcode" class="coupon-placeholder placeholder"  type="text"/>               
        <input type='submit' name='coupon_code_submit' value='Apply' id="cart-coupon" class="sp_apply_btn" >      
  </form>



     jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('form#coupon_discount').submit(function(e){
             var   user     = jQuery('input[name="user"]', 'form#coupon_discount').val();
             var couponcode = jQuery('input[name="couponcode"]', 'form#coupon_discount').val();
             if(user != '' && couponcode != '') {
             e.preventDefault();
             var URL = '<?php echo $_conf_vars['ROOT_URL']."ajax.php?usercp=";?>'+user+'&cponcode='+couponcode;
             jQuery.ajax({
                        url:URL,
                        type:'POST',
                        async:true
                      }).done(function(msg,e){
                        if(msg=='Already used!'){ 
                          alert('Coupon code already used!');
                         }else {  
                          jQuery('form#coupon_discount').submit();  
                         }
                      }); 
                   }
                   else{
                     e.preventDefault();
                     alert('Enter a coupon code!');
                   }    
             });  
        });
```

And this the action page 'checkcoupon.php' code.

```
  session_start();
    ob_start();

    include("includes/files.php");
    include("classes/class.common.php");

    if(isset($_REQUEST['coupon_code_submit']))
    {
        $obj_common = new common;
        $discount = $obj_common->getCouponCodeDiscount($_REQUEST['couponcode'],$_REQUEST['user']); 
        header("location:payment.php");
    }
```

Comment: what I want to achieve here is that if the coupon code is already used then the form (with coupon code input field) is not submitted.So I check if it has been used before using ajax, and if it is so then give a alert message and submit the form only when the code is not used before. The second e.preventDefault is for the case when the input field is blank.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('form#coupon_discount').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();   //Put here and do the stuff

         });  
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the `e.preventDefault()` call inside an asynchronous callback. By the time the code gets there, it's already too late.

Move the `e.preventDefault()` outside the callback.